# Nested `each` loops in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Need guidance on the syntax of nested looping in groovy. How to use iterator to print values of (value of a.name, value of b.name) here?

```
List a
a.each {
    print(it.name)
    List b = something
    b.each {
        print(value of a.name, value of b.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
List a
a.each { x ->
    println(x.name)
    List b = something
    b.each { y ->
        println(x.name + y.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to stop processing when encountering some condition, or skip the `a` or `b` for some condition, then you'd need to use the `for`-`in` loop because the `break` and `continue` keywords don't work --or more accurately, work in an unexpected manner-- with `each` method enclosures.

Comment: how about return? I have a return statement inside nested each loops and the return statement seems to have been ignored

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461947/6509