# Break from each loop when match found

Tags: groovy

I have an array of strings and I am trying to look for the string that matches a certain regex. As soon as it finds the first match, I would like to break/exit out of the each loop. My code is

```
imagePathPrefix = "aab"
destinations.each{
  if(it.startsWith(imagePathPrefix)){
  // As soon as the first match is found, do something and then exit out of each !
}
```

`destination` looks like

```
[aabb, aabbbbb, abbbb, aaaaaabb, abababa]
```

As soon as it matches with `aabb`, I would like to exit/break out of the each loop.

**EDIT:**

Ive added `return true` but it does not work

```
destinations = ['aabb', 'abbbb', 'aaaaaabb', 'abababa']

println destinations

println destinations.getClass()

destinations.each{
    if(it.startsWith('aab')){
        println "a found"
        return true
    } else {
        println "a not found"
    }
}​
```

Result:

```
[aabb, abbbb, aaaaaabb, abababa]
class java.util.ArrayList
a found
a not found
a not found
a not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to break out of closure in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336704/is-it-possible-to-break-out-of-closure-in-groovy)

Comment: Rule of thumb: `each` is for sideeffects only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *groovy* way to *find* the first element of a collection that meet some condition is to use [`find`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#List-Filtering)

```
println destinations.find {it.startsWith(imagePathPrefix)}
```

returns for your data

```
aabb
```