# Groovy - how to exit each loop?

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I'm new to Grails/Groovy and am trying to find a node in a an xml file; I've figured out how to iterate over all of them, but I want to exit the loop when the target node is found. I've read that instead of using "each", use "find", but the find examples I've seen are conditions. Right now the logic I have is going to iterate through the whole file without exiting. The code is below:

```java
  records.children().each {domain ->
   println "domain_name: " + domain.@domain_name
   if (domain.@domain_name == targetDomain) {
    
    println "target domain matched: " + domain.@domain_name
        
    domain.children().each {misc_field ->
     
     println "field_name: " + misc_field.@field_name
     println "field_type: " + misc_field.@field_type
     println "field_value: " + misc_field
     
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You cannot do it elegantly. You might see some people suggest throwing an Exception, but that's just [plain ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control).

Here's some [mailing list discussion](http://old.nabble.com/using-.each%7B%7D-versus-traditional-for-loop-td25435659.html) on using `each` vs. `for`, and a couple people say that `for` is preferred because of `each`'s inability to break from the iteration.

Your best bet is probably to change over to a `for` loop and iterate:

```
for(def domain : records.children()) { // this may need some tweaking depending on types
    // do stuff
    if(condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Either that, or like you said, maybe use [find](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Quick+Start#QuickStart-find) or [findAll](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Quick+Start#QuickStart-findAll) to find the element you're looking for (the following code is paraphrased, I don't have time yet to test it out):

```
def result = records.children().find { domain -> domain.@domain_name == targetDomain }
result.children().each {
    // print stuff
}
```

Related SO questions:

- [best-pattern-for-simulating-continue-in-groovy-closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205660/best-pattern-for-simulating-continue-in-groovy-closure)
- [is-it-possible-to-break-out-of-closure-in-groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336704/is-it-possible-to-break-out-of-closure-in-groovy)

Comment: But in the original problem by Jack, did he even need to break? It seems to me that the intent is to (in pseudo-groovy because i've never used it) records.children.find( @domain_name = targetDomain ).children().each (println)

Comment: @neonski - Yeah, I was just working on an edit to my answer with some code like you paraphrased. I think that's probably the more ideal solution.

Comment: @Jack - Can you clarify which one worked (for future readers' sake)? If it wasn't the `find` solution, you might try that too, just for the sake of experience. It's a bit more of a groovy-ish solution.

Comment: Sure - I actually posted the answer before I had refreshed the comments. I used the first solution. I tried the second one, but the compiler says "unexpected token" at the "=" sign in this: @domain_name = targetDomain.

Comment: @Jack - Did you use `==` or `=`? (Not that I'd expect using `=` would throw an "unexpected token" error.) Also, using `domain.'@domain_name'` *might* work, but again, not sure.

Comment: +1 for using Find in this case. It's concise, and I find that using Find or FindAll is super handy, and makes the code easy to understand and test.

Comment: why is there a semicolon after the "break" keyword?

Answer (score 11):

Replace **each** loop with **any** or **find** closure.

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list.any { element ->
    if (element == 2)
        return // continue

    println element

    if (element == 3)
        true // break
}
```

Output

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding breaking out of the each loop see: [is it possible to 'break' out of a groovy closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336704/is-it-possible-to-break-out-of-closure-in-groovy)

Basically you have to throw and exception and catch it. The "break" keyword is only allowed inside loops not iterated "closures" (really code blocks).

You can use any complex code with "find" just make sure the function you call returns a Boolean. For example:

```
Boolean test(val) {
    println "Testing $val"
    return val == 1
}

def found = [3,4,5,1,6,3].find { test(it) }

println "Found $found"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work too, stopping at the first match.

```
def result = records.children().find { domain -> 
    if (domain.@domain_name == targetDomain) {
        // Do stuff
        ...
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```