# how to break the _.each function in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm looking for a way to stop iterations of underscore.js `_.each()` method, but can't find the solution. jQuery `.each()` can break if you do `return false`.

Is there a way to stop underscore each()?

```
_([1,2,3]).each(function(v){
    if (v==2) return /*what?*/;
})
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because the native `forEach` function does not offer this feature either.

Comment: Normally when using `each` with a closure (in most languages), you want to filter your list first. That way you don't have to worry about breaking from it. Generally speaking, if you need to break early from an iteration, there's probably a different way that you could be doing it.

Comment: [Here are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766941/groovy-how-to-exit-each-loop/1767046) [a couple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/break-from-groovy-each-closure) related questions for Groovy, where the behavior (inability to conveniently break from an `each` closure) is similar to JavaScript.

Comment: @Dmitry_F, as others have noted, you can't do exactly what you're asking. But as I demonstrated, you can use `Array.every` to emulate the behavior you want.

Comment: @Rob. Cheers. First comment really helpful. Indeed there was a different way I could have been doing it.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can't break from the `each` method—it emulates the native `forEach` method's behavior, and the native `forEach` doesn't provide to escape the loop (other than throwing an exception).

**However, all hope is not lost!** You can use the [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method. :)

From that link:

> `every` executes the provided `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where `callback` returns a false value. If such an element is found, the `every` method immediately returns false.

In other words, you could do something convoluted like this ([link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdleyEskridge/x2pVx/)):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].every(function(n) {
    alert(n);
    return n !== 3;
});
```

This will alert `1` through `3`, and then "break" out of the loop.

You're using underscore.js, so you'll be pleased to learn that it *does* provide an `every` method—they call it [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every), but as that link mentions, they also provide an alias called `all`.

Comment: Does underscore.js provide an implementation for this as well?

Comment: @FelixKling, yes it does. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: you can use either _.every or _.all at the present time

Comment: right now (05/2013), there is neither a `_.every()` nor a `_.all()` method for arrays in underscore - so stick to the `Array.every()`.

Comment: Here is a fork of the fiddle in case you want to break by array index instead: http://jsfiddle.net/x2pVx/66/

Comment: This will work, but it's an usual reason for using `every`. So watch out for readability.

Comment: The underscore docs for `_.each()` has a note specifically about the fact that you can't break out of the loop, and recommend that you use `_.find()` instead.  [http://underscorejs.org/#each](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

Comment: @wil93 ,@aeskr can you just tell me where control will go after execution of return statement.

Answer (score 71):

Update:

_.find would be better as it breaks out of the loop when the element is found:

```
var searchArr = [{id:1,text:"foo"},{id:2,text:"bar"}];
var count = 0;
var filteredEl = _.find(searchArr,function(arrEl){ 
              count = count +1;
              if(arrEl.id === 1 ){
                  return arrEl;
              }
            });

console.log(filteredEl);
//since we are searching the first element in the array, the count will be one
console.log(count);
//output: filteredEl : {id:1,text:"foo"} , count: 1
```

** Old **

If you want to conditionally break out of a loop, use _.filter api instead of _.each. Here is a code snippet

```
var searchArr = [{id:1,text:"foo"},{id:2,text:"bar"}];
var filteredEl = _.filter(searchArr,function(arrEl){ 
                  if(arrEl.id === 1 ){
                      return arrEl;
                  }
                });
console.log(filteredEl);
//output: {id:1,text:"foo"}
```

Comment: this doesn't break the loop - it just filters the array. imagine you have have not 2 but 20.000 items in the array. you log would only output the example you posted but the loop would run 20.000 times :(

Comment: @pkyeck you are right, may be _.find is better than _.filter as it breaks after the elemnt is found, here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/niki4810/9K3EV/

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as the correct one. `_.find` does exactly what is asked : iterate over the list until the callback returns `true`.

Comment: Voted for this answer because the accepted answer (Array.every) won't work on objects, but _.find() will.

Comment: And that's what is recommnded in the docs: It's also good to note that an each loop cannot be broken out of — to break, use _.find instead.

Answer (score 17):

You can have a look to `_.some` instead of `_.each`.
`_.some` stops traversing the list once a predicate is true.
Result(s) can be stored in an external variable.

```
_.some([1, 2, 3], function(v) {
    if (v == 2) return true;
})
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#some

Answer (score 6):

```
_([1,2,3]).find(function(v){
    return v if (v==2);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot break a `forEach` in underscore, as it emulates EcmaScript 5 native behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want Underscore's any() or find(), which will stop processing when a condition is met.

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answers, it's impossible.
Here is the comment about breaker in underscore [underscore issue #21](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/211)

Answer (score 2):

I believe if your array was actually an object you could return using an empty object.

```
_.({1,2,3,4,5}).each(function(v){  
  if(v===3) return {}; 
});
```

Comment: That only happens with EcmaScript v < 5 as the comparison that underscore does to check if you are returning the empty object in the provided alternative to forEach is only done when the native one is not available.

Answer (score 2):

> It's also good to note that an each loop cannot be broken out of — to
>   break, use _.find instead.

http://underscorejs.org/#each

Answer (score 1):

Update:

You can actually "break" by throwing an error inside and catching it outside: something like this:

```
try{
  _([1,2,3]).each(function(v){
    if (v==2) throw new Error('break');
  });
}catch(e){
  if(e.message === 'break'){
    //break successful
  }
}
```

This obviously has some implications regarding any other exceptions that your code trigger in the loop, so use with caution!

Comment: Love how I get so many down votes for this, and this guy gets a whole load of ups for his http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641374/674720

Comment: I'm late to the party but note that guy not only said what you suggested, but offered two more alternatives (and more suitable). The only offered the "hack" in case the user by all means want it. You instead only offered the ugly hack.

Answer (score -1):

worked in my case

```
var arr2 = _.filter(arr, function(item){
    if ( item == 3 ) return item;
});
```