# Break out of an _.each loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, break

Is it possible to break out of an underscore each loop..?

```
_.each(obj, function(v,i){
  if(i > 2){
    break // <~ does not work
  }
  // some code here
  // ...
})
```

Is there another design pattern I can be using?

Comment: I don't know Javascript, but wouldn't `return` work?

Comment: @Pubby It would return, and the loop would continue, and it would return again. I want to break, and stop looping.

Comment: You can try the Array.every method instead.

From:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779799/how-to-break-the-each-function-in-underscore-js

Comment: @Pubby The `.each` method would **have** to look for that and break the looping its doing, otherwise it'll just keep going.

Comment: @jsalonen why did you delete your answer - looks like the answer I was looking for - is there a problem with it?

Comment: In case anybody cares, jQuery's `each` function does let you do this. If you `return false;` it stops looping through the values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can, so you will just have to wrap the contents of the function in `i < 2` or use `return`.  It may make more sense to use `.some` or `.every`.

EDIT:

```
//pseudo break
_.each(obj, function (v, i) {
    if (i <= 2) {
        // some code here
        // ...
    }
});
```

The issue with the above is of course that it has to do the entire loop, but that is simply a weakness of underscore's `each`.

You could use `.every`, though (either native array method or underscore's method):

```
_.every(obj, function (v, i) {
    // some code here
    // ...
    return i <= 2;
});
```

Comment: p.s. from underscore docs (don't know how recent):

"an [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) loop cannot be broken out of — to break, use [_.find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) instead"

Answer (score 0):

For now you cannot break an each loop. It is being discussed here: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/596

Maybe on a future version.