# Sailsjs - Continue executing after return res.json();

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

It continues execution even if the condition is true and return res.json() is executed.

```
_.each(rooms, function(room){
    if(room.users.length == users.length) {
        return res.json(room); // <-- returns but still continuous execution
    }
});
```

Below is the error printed in console.

> error: Error: Cannot write to response more than once

Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in [How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery), you can **exit `each` loops by returning `false`**. Thus,

```
_.each(rooms, function(room){
    if(room.users.length == users.length) {
        res.json(room);
        return false;
    }
});
```

If that did not work and you used underscore.js, see [how to break the _.each function in underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779799/how-to-break-the-each-function-in-underscore-js) which recommends using `.every` where `return false` works (instead of `.each`). Thus

```
_.every(rooms, function(room){
    if(room.users.length == users.length) {
        res.json(room);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should break the loop and then `res.status(200).json(room)`

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, But as its a callback function the break is not working there. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a different function in the underscore/lodash api, for example, find would seem to suit what you are doing better:

```
var room = _.find(rooms, function(room){
  return room.users.length == users.length;
});
res.json(room);
```

Comment: This is awesome. :) I changed my code. This works great. Thanks