# How to use "continue" in groovy's each loop

Tags: for-loop, groovy, each, continue

I am new to groovy (worked on java), trying to write some test cases using Spock framework.
I need the following Java snippet converted into groovy snippet using "each loop"

### Java Snippet:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");
for( String myObj : myList){
    if(myObj==null) {
        continue;   // need to convert this part in groovy using each loop
    }
    System.out.println("My Object is "+ myObj);
}
```

Groovy Snippet:

```
def myObj = ["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"]
myList.each{ myObj->
    if(myObj==null){
        //here I need to continue
    }
    println("My Object is " + myObj)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best pattern for simulating "continue" in Groovy closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205660/best-pattern-for-simulating-continue-in-groovy-closure)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Either use `return`, as the closure basically is a method that is called with each element as parameter like

```
def myObj = ["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"]
myList.each{ myObj->
    if(myObj==null){
        return
    }
    println("My Object is " + myObj)
}
```

Or switch your pattern to

```
def myObj = ["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"]
myList.each{ myObj->
    if(myObj!=null){
        println("My Object is " + myObj)
    }
}
```

Or use a `findAll` before to filter out `null` objects

```
def myList = ["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", null, "You"]
myList.findAll { it != null }.each{ myObj->
    println("My Object is " + myObj)
}
```

Or if you are concerned that you first iterate through the whole collection to filter and only then start with the `each`, you can also leverage Java streams

```
def myList = ["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", null, "You"]
myList.stream().filter { it != null }.each{ myObj->
    println("My Object is " + myObj)
}
```

Comment: OP wants to filter entries and therefore `findAll {...}` is the top answer here +1

Comment: Last version with findAll looks the niciest. But isn't that more time consuming? Aren't you iterating over the whole collection twice then?

Comment: I don't think it is significantly more time-consuming as you do the same actions even with iterating twice. The `each` will not start though until the filtering is done. If that is an issue, you can leverage Java streams. I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 27):

you can either use a standard `for` loop with `continue`:

```
for( String myObj in myList ){
  if( something ) continue
  doTheRest()
}
```

or use `return` in `each`'s closure:

```
myList.each{ myObj->
  if( something ) return
  doTheRest()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also only enter your `if` statement if the object isn't `null`.

```
def myObj = ["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"]
myList.each{ 
    myObj->
    if(myObj!=null){
        println("My Object is " + myObj)
    }
}
```

Comment: code is cleaner with the "continue" approach, when there is a lot of code to be executed when the condition is not satisfied.